# Scala overloading not choosing most specific method

Tags: java, scala, oop, overloading

Having Java classes:

```
class abstract Exp
class ExpAdd extends Exp
class ExpSub extends Exp
```

and Scala methods:

```
def interpret(e: ExpAdd) = interpret(e.left_arg) + interpret(e.right_arg)
def interpret(e: ExpSub) = interpret(e.left_arg) - interpret(e.right_arg)

def interpret(exp: Exp) = exp match {
  case e : ExpAdd = interpret(e)
  case e : ExpSub = interpret(e)
}
```

How to **refactor** the code to make **adding new Exps easier**? I thought interpret(Exp) wouldn't be used at all as two other are more specific and

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

however that seems not to be the case in Scala. I also tried removing interpret(Exp) but compiler didn't like it. That's why I used case clause... is there any way to make overloading work as expected? or maybe some workaround?

Comment: It looks like you only have one method called `make`, so of course calls to `make` are going to call `make`?

Comment: My mistake here. All the methods have same name. The mistake comes from my attempt at shortening the case. I've just edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Alexy says, the method resolution is based on the compile-time or "static" type of the arguments. You could make the types of the operands part of the type of the expression, and then use implicits to recursively construct the interpreter for a given type:

```
trait Exp
case class ExpAdd[A <: Exp, B <: Exp](left_arg: A, right_arg: B) extends Exp
case class ExpSub[A <: Exp, B <: Exp](left_arg: A, right_arg: B) extends Exp
case class Literal(i: Int) extends Exp

trait ExpInterpreter[E <: Exp] {
  def interpret(e: E): Int
}
object ExpInterpreter {
  implicit object LiteralInterpreter extends Interpreter[Literal] {
    def interpret(l: Literal) = l.i
  }
  implicit def addInterpreter[A <: Exp, B <: Exp](
    implicit leftInterpreter: Interpreter[A], rightInterpreter: Interpreter[B]) =
    new Interpreter[ExpAdd[A, B]] {
      def interpret(e: ExpAdd[A, B]) = leftInterpreter.interpret(e.left_arg) +
        rightInterpreter.interpret(e.right_arg)
    }
  implicit def subInterpreter ...
}
```

Then when you add new `Exp` cases you just need to define a new implicit, and you can do that anywhere rather than having to add a case to a particular match expression. You could even have `Exp` and `ExpInterpreter` in a library and the cases and specific interpreters in a different jar.

As written this means the structure of an expression is part of its type (and you have to carry the type around until you interpret it - there's no way to interpret a generic `Exp`, only an `E <: Exp: ExpInterpreter`), but maybe it's possible to use a similar technique to the [Free monad](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Free+Monad.html) to overcome this?

Comment: Free monad sounds interesting, I'll study it carefully. I'm afraid that it would require me to modify Java classes, which I'd prefer to avoid as they are output from an independent tool. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `Exp` and `interpret` are not fully visible and not sure I understand what you are trying to represent but here's 2 ideas:

- Try to use operator overloading defining a `+` and a `-` methods for more DSL-esque operations
- Even better so, you can think of the addition, subtraction or any other operation as *bahaviours* and define them as functions. This way (single data representation with multiple behavioural units) your code will follow more FP principles.

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking about interpret not make... I've just edited the question so that it matches the case. 1. I don't want to use operator overloading because I will be also interpreting expressions with only one 'argument' - like interpet(ExpVar). 2. The behaviours are defined in my interpret function but Scala seems to ignore precedence of more specific methods.

Answer (score 1):

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

This is the same in Java and Scala: which overload is used is chosen *at compile-time* (and then this specific overload is *dispatched* at run-time, as the quote says). Since `e.left_arg` is not known to be either `ExpAdd` or `ExpSub`, the compiler can only choose `interpret(exp: Exp)` and complains when you remove it. One option is to remove the other overloads instead:

```
def interpret(exp: Exp) = exp match {
  case e : ExpAdd => interpret(e.left_arg) + interpret(e.right_arg)
  case e : ExpSub => interpret(e.left_arg) - interpret(e.right_arg)
}

// when extending
override def interpret(exp: Exp) = exp match {
  case e : ExpMult => interpret(e.left_arg) * interpret(e.right_arg)
  case _ => super.interpret(exp)
}
```